# MySQL How to join 2 tables and get a combined response

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables projects and images. My goal is to get all images of a project and get this kind of response.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "this is project id",
    "title": "project title",
    ...
    "images": [
      {
         "image": "images/image-name.jpg",
      },
      {
         "image": "images/image-name.jpg",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But what I get is this

```
{
  "data": [
     {
       "image": "image-path.jpg"
     },
     {
       "image": "image-path.jpg"
     }
   ]
}
```

My table structure look like this

`projects`

| id | title | description | collaboration | role | case_study | slug | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | text | text | text | text | text | text | enum(ltr, rtl) |

`images`

| id | images | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | image_path | uuid |

My current query looks like this

```
`SELECT images.image FROM images JOIN projects ON images.project_id = ${id}`
```

Comment: You cannot get the result you want with a query alone. You will have to query the database and then with some program manipuldate the resultset to your desired output

Comment: By doing this `SELECT images.image` you are asking to get only images returned. Try adding the project fields into the SELECT as well and take it from there

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to combine your queries from two tables to one json:

```
SELECT json_object(
    'id',p.id,
    'title',p.title,
    'images',( select json_arrayagg(json_object('image',i.`image`)) from images i where i.project_id = 1 )
) as json
FROM projects p WHERE p.id = 1;
```

You will get this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "gx",
"images": [
    {
        "image": "foo"
    },
    {
        "image": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

But finally i have to say that combine your query result in your code is the better way.